# Re-aligning text in Eclipse Draw2D Label

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, draw2d

I am building an RCP-based application with Draw2D Labels (Figures with text).  When my graphical editor re-sizes the label, the text stays in it's initial position.  Is there anyway to have the text reposition based on the new constraints of the label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you just need to use the setConstriants(IFigure parent, Rectangle bounds) method to set the bounds of the label that is residing on top of the parent figure.